# Are the aliens in the Doctor Who universe subject to human law?

Tags: doctor-who

Suppose, for example, that the UK authorities issued an arrest warrant on the belief that he was involved in some felonious act, and he's in outer space. Would he be facing extradition to the UK?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WkRC_IQu0A

Comment: @calccrypto: If he then stepped into the jurisdiction of some alien law enforcement agency who found out he had a warrant in the UK for that act, would the said agency hold him for extradition to the UK?

Comment: sigh.... can no one take a joke anymore?

Comment: -1; Well, assuming you mean modern day UK, which to my knowledge has no diplomatic relations of any kind with any alien species and therefore couldn't possibly get the proper paperwork in order, let alone thumb down the next invading alien of the week and convince it to act as mail courier over a spot of tea, and with the triplicate 221Bs still on backorder from Alpha Centauri.......... no.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on which time line or time period, and the extradition treaties in place between a space faring Earth and said alien police jurisdiction.

A reverse situation happened in the Season 3 opener where the Doctor meets Martha Jones. The Shadow Proclamation and it's Judoon police force have no jurisdiction on Earth, so they go around it by teleporting the hospital with the criminal they were looking for to the moon. In accordance with Galactic law, they also provided an atmosphere for the Hospital.

Comment: They were exploiting a loophole, I'd imagine.